# write two list in file bin in C#

Tags: list, file

I have  two list i want send  them to bin file but with this method
i can send one of them ! is it possible use this method if yes please help

```
var mystudent=List<student>();
var mycourse=List<course>();



string dir = @"D:\";
        string serializationFile = Path.Combine(dir, "Student.bin");
            //serialize
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(serializationFile, FileMode.Create))
            {
                var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

                bformatter.Serialize(stream, mystudentList);
            }

            //  deserialize
            using (Stream stream = File.Open(serializationFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var bformatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

                List<student> stud = (List<student>)bformatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
```

Comment: @user3758039 What is exactly your question? You should edit your message and clarify it.

Comment: how serialize 2 list to bin file...?  i can serialize one list to file ... and i want serialize two list to bin file understand?